# Convolution product $f*f$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

Let $f$ be the function defined by
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
f :  [-1,1] & \longrightarrow & {\mathbb R}\\ 
\quad x &\longmapsto & \sqrt{1-x^2}
\end{array}
$$
I would like to calculate the convolution product $f*f$ in terms of the elliptic integrals $$K(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1 - xt^2)}}$$ and $$E(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1 - xt^2}}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)}}dt$$ More precisely I would like to prove :$$f*f(x)=\left|\frac{2x}{3}\left((x^2+4)E\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)-8K\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)\right)\right|.$$

Can someone help me to prove the above formula?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community, The question is how one can find the above formula of $f*f$

Comment: I believe the result is actually $f * f=\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} \left(\left(x^2+4\right) E\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)-2 x^2 K\left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\right) & -2<x<2 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$ where $E$ and $K$ are the elliptic $E$ and elliptic $K$ functions.

Comment: You seem to have your $E$ and $K$ definitions reversed.

Comment: @StevenClark, could you please explain your calculation?

Comment: I evaluated the inverse Fourier transform of the square of the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ using Mathematica. The initial result was a Meijer G function which I was able to expand and simplify into the two elliptic functions.

Comment: I noticed that your conjectured result seems to be 4x the result I defined above, so it appears your conjectured result (or perhaps my result) is only off by a multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Fourier transform of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (supported on $[-1,1]$) is given by $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\frac{J_1(s)}{s}$ with $J_1(s)$ being the Bessel function
$$ J_1(s) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^{n+1}n!(n+1)!} s^{2n+1} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(s\sin\theta-\theta)\,d\theta $$
so the problem boils down to finding the inverse Fourier transform of $J_1(s)^2/s^2$. By Vandermonde's identity the square of a Bessel function of the first kind also have a nice power series (see page 26 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3o7ehDI3u7-n-cYV1JOpKifw7IZY3mN/view?usp=sharing)). In our case
$$ J_1(s)^2/s^2 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^{n+1} n!(n+2)!}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}s^{2n}\tag{1}$$
and the Laplace transform of this function is clearly related to $K$ and $E$ (the complete elliptic integrals) since (according to Mathematica's notation)
$$ K(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\right)^2 x^n,\qquad E(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\right)^2 \frac{x^n}{1-2n} $$
while, due to $(1)$,

$$\mathcal{L}\left(J_1(s)^2/s^2\right)(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{4^{n+1}n!(n+2)!}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}\frac{(2n)!}{x^{2n+1}}=\frac{x}{2}\left(-1+\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};2;-\tfrac{4}{x^2}\right)\right). $$

In order to finish the job it is enough to exploit the relation between the inverse Fourier transform and the Laplace transform, which in our case turns out to be just a matter of introducing/removing alternating signs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I believe the Fourier transform of $f*g$ is equal to product of the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$ when the Fourier transform is defined as $\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{i x y}\,dx$ or perhaps $\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{-i x y}\,dx$, whereas you seem to have used the definition $\mathcal{F}_x[f(x)](y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{i x y}\,dx$.

Comment: Yes, of course, that depends on the choice of the normalization constant, but the essence remains the same (up to constant factors).

Comment: Could you please expand a little on how one can get the convolution $f*f$ in terms of the complete elliptic integrals from the Laplace transform of $J_1(s)^2/s^2$?